# How to make combination in drilldown in highcharts / add outliers in boxplot in drilldown?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, combinations, boxplot, drilldown

I asked one question recently, but this is a new, relevant yet total different one. I would like to add outliers in boxplot which is in drilldown. I am able to do that in primary plot, in a combination way that boxplot is in one series while outliers are in another series as 'scatter'. As in follows:

```
series : [ {type : 'boxplot' , ...} , {type : 'scatter' ,...} ]
```

But as now my boxplot is in drilldown, whose series denotes different drilldowns/figures, I can not add outliers in boxplot. As in follows:

```
drilldown : { series : [ {type : 'boxplot' , name : 's1' , id : 's1' , ...} , {type : 'scatter' , name : 's1' , id : 's1' , ...} ] }
```

It would be useless have them use the same id and name, for latter one would cover the formal one. Hence, my current boxplot's drilldown boxplot have no outliers. As show below.

```js
Highcharts.setOptions({
     colors: ['#33FFFF', '#3399FF' , '#3333FF' , '#9933FF' , '#FF33FF' , '#FF3399' , '#FF3333' , '#FF9933' , '#FFFF33' , '#99FF33' , '#33FF33' , '#00F57A' , '#00B85C' ]
    });

$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'boxplot'
        },
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'category',

            title: {
                text: ''
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'RPKM'
            }
        },
        plotOptions : {
            boxplot : {
                medianColor: '#FFFFFF',
                medianWidth: 1.2
            }
        },
        series: [
{data: [                    
                   {
x : 0,
low : 137.454800 ,
q1 : 193.180600 ,
median : 239.781500 ,
q3 : 268.534200 ,
high : 307.995100 ,
pointWidth : 24,fillColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],name:'Early prenatal A'
,drilldown:'a0'
}

,
{
x : 1,
low : 92.917810 ,
q1 : 136.239360 ,
median : 155.951450 ,
q3 : 169.681420 ,
high : 215.367540 ,
pointWidth : 24,fillColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1],color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1],name:'Early prenatal B'
,drilldown:'a1'
}

,
{
x : 2,
low : 129.687600 ,
q1 : 155.824800 ,
median : 177.170200 ,
q3 : 209.450400 ,
high : 284.302400 ,
pointWidth : 24,fillColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2],color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2],name:'Early mid-prenatal A'
,drilldown:'a2'
}

,
{
x : 3,
low : 55.805900 ,
q1 : 117.463500 ,
median : 139.745800 ,
q3 : 170.863200 ,
high : 230.989900 ,
pointWidth : 24,fillColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[3],color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[3],name:'Early mid-prenatal B'
,drilldown:'a3'
}

,
{
x : 4,
low : 65.473830 ,
q1 : 106.122030 ,
median : 122.133410 ,
q3 : 139.876510 ,
high : 179.184210 ,
pointWidth : 24,fillColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[4],color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[4],name:'Late mid-prenatal'
,drilldown:'a4'
}

,
{
x : 5,
low : 29.982680 ,
q1 : 68.503770 ,
median : 89.739910 ,
q3 : 98.614430 ,
high : 138.395890 ,
pointWidth : 24,fillColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[5],color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[5],name:'Late prenatal'
,drilldown:'a5'
}

,
{
x : 6,
low : 19.978470 ,
q1 : 39.705310 ,
median : 51.624160 ,
q3 : 60.536260 ,
high : 83.889140 ,
pointWidth : 24,fillColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[6],color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[6],name:'Early infancy'
,drilldown:'a6'
}

,
{
x : 7,
low : 50.679100 ,
q1 : 55.191780 ,
median : 58.813590 ,
q3 : 61.126990 ,
high : 68.266470 ,
pointWidth : 24,fillColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[7],color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[7],name:'Late infancy'
,drilldown:'a7'
}

,
{
x : 8,
low : 15.138200 ,
q1 : 30.538220 ,
median : 37.540280 ,
q3 : 42.228450 ,
high : 49.069710 ,
pointWidth : 24,fillColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[8],color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[8],name:'Early childhood'
,drilldown:'a8'
}

,
{
x : 9,
low : 18.499100 ,
q1 : 25.500380 ,
median : 30.374310 ,
q3 : 36.269800 ,
high : 51.134470 ,
pointWidth : 24,fillColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[9],color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[9],name:'Late childhood'
,drilldown:'a9'
}

,
{
x : 10,
low : 22.025020 ,
q1 : 29.279230 ,
median : 36.748660 ,
q3 : 46.518430 ,
high : 67.598710 ,
pointWidth : 24,fillColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[10],color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[10],name:'Adolescence'
,drilldown:'a10'
}

,
{
x : 11,
low : 10.235750 ,
q1 : 26.566710 ,
median : 33.398670 ,
q3 : 40.092060 ,
high : 59.317570 ,
pointWidth : 24,fillColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[11],color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[11],name:'Adulthood'
,drilldown:'a11'
}
],
name:'Stage Level',
tooltip: {
//headerFormat: 'Observation:',
footerFormat: '<em>{point.key}</em><br/>'
 }

  }


 ,{tooltip:{pointFormat:'{point.y} in {point.fname}'},name: 'Outlier',color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1],type: 'scatter',data: [
 {x: 1 ,y: 239.721302 ,fname:'Early prenatal B'},
 {x: 1 ,y: 55.716973 ,fname:'Early prenatal B'}, 
 {x: 1 ,y: 76.719418 ,fname:'Early prenatal B'}, 
 {x: 1 ,y: 64.015346 ,fname:'Early prenatal B'}, 
 ],marker:{symbol : 'circle'}}
 ,{tooltip:{pointFormat:'{point.y} in {point.fname}'},name: 'Outlier',color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[4],type: 'scatter',data: [
 {x: 4 ,y: 54.518196 ,fname:'Late mid-prenatal'},
 ],marker:{symbol : 'circle'}}
 ,{tooltip:{pointFormat:'{point.y} in {point.fname}'},name: 'Outlier',color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[6],type: 'scatter',data: [
 {x: 6 ,y: 116.422878 ,fname:'Early infancy'},
 ],marker:{symbol : 'circle'}}
 ,{tooltip:{pointFormat:'{point.y} in {point.fname}'},name: 'Outlier',color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[7],type: 'scatter',data: [
 {x: 7 ,y: 87.81937 ,fname:'Late infancy'},
 ],marker:{symbol : 'circle'}}
 ,{tooltip:{pointFormat:'{point.y} in {point.fname}'},name: 'Outlier',color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[8],type: 'scatter',data: [
 {x: 8 ,y: 79.751904 ,fname:'Early childhood'},
 {x: 8 ,y: 74.559397 ,fname:'Early childhood'},
 {x: 8 ,y: 77.572389 ,fname:'Early childhood'},
 {x: 8 ,y: 71.848965 ,fname:'Early childhood'},
 ],marker:{symbol : 'circle'}}
 ,{tooltip:{pointFormat:'{point.y} in {point.fname}'},name: 'Outlier',color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[9],type: 'scatter',data: [
 {x: 9 ,y: 102.364761 ,fname:'Late childhood'},
 {x: 9 ,y: 84.559888 ,fname:'Late childhood'}, 
 ],marker:{symbol : 'circle'}}
 ,{tooltip:{pointFormat:'{point.y} in {point.fname}'},name: 'Outlier',color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[10],type: 'scatter',data: [
 {x: 10 ,y: 74.638885 ,fname:'Adolescence'},
 {x: 10 ,y: 85.489912 ,fname:'Adolescence'},
 ],marker:{symbol : 'circle'}}
 ,{tooltip:{pointFormat:'{point.y} in {point.fname}'},name: 'Outlier',color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[11],type: 'scatter',data: [
 {x: 11 ,y: 80.671587 ,fname:'Adulthood'},
 {x: 11 ,y: 64.98078 ,fname:'Adulthood'}, 
 {x: 11 ,y: 73.643196 ,fname:'Adulthood'},
 {x: 11 ,y: 63.109206 ,fname:'Adulthood'},
 {x: 11 ,y: 106.44305 ,fname:'Adulthood'},
 {x: 11 ,y: 81.019643 ,fname:'Adulthood'},
 {x: 11 ,y: 72.517182 ,fname:'Adulthood'},
 ],marker:{symbol : 'circle'}}
        ],

        drilldown: {
            series: [

                {
                id: 'aa1',
                type: 'column',
                data: [{
                    y: 39.9,
                    name: 'name1'
                    }, {
                    y: 31.5,
                    name: 'name2'
                      }]
                },
{tooltip:{pointFormat:'{point.y} in {point.fname}'},name : 'Sample Level',id : 'a0' ,color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1],type: 'scatter',data: [
 {x: 1 ,y: 239.721302 ,fname:'Early prenatal B'},
 {x: 1 ,y: 55.716973 ,fname:'Early prenatal B'}, 
 {x: 1 ,y: 76.719418 ,fname:'Early prenatal B'}, 
 {x: 1 ,y: 64.015346 ,fname:'Early prenatal B'}, 
 ],marker:{symbol : 'circle'}}
 ,

{
name : 'Sample Level',id : 'a0' ,
type : 'boxplot', 
data: [{x : 0 ,
name : 'H376.IIA.51',fillColor : Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],low : 177.242900 ,
q1 : 205.072600 ,
median : 242.331500 ,
q3 : 272.279300 ,
high : 307.995100 ,
},{x : 1 ,
name : 'H376.IIA.50',fillColor : Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],low : 137.454800 ,
q1 : 179.522800 ,
median : 228.641600 ,
q3 : 249.357900 ,
high : 306.817900 ,
}]},{
name : 'Sample Level',id : 'a1' ,
type : 'boxplot', 
data: [{x : 0 ,
name : 'H376.IIB.50',fillColor : Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1],low : 138.932100 ,
q1 : 154.910100 ,
median : 159.421800 ,
q3 : 166.705900 ,
high : 170.136700 ,
},{x : 1 ,
name : 'H376.IIB.51',fillColor : Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1],low : 135.210200 ,
q1 : 147.937900 ,
median : 169.681400 ,
q3 : 178.332200 ,
high : 210.950000 ,
},{x : 2 ,
name : 'H376.IIB.52',fillColor : Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1],low : 92.917810 ,
q1 : 122.379250 ,
median : 136.239360 ,
q3 : 146.694490 ,
high : 161.036110 ,
}]},{
name : 'Sample Level',id : 'a2' ,
type : 'boxplot', 
data: [{x : 0 ,
name : 'H376.IIIA.50',fillColor : Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2],low : 129.934000 ,
q1 : 152.116600 ,
median : 159.479200 ,
q3 : 173.120800 ,
high : 195.116700 ,
},{x : 1 ,
name : 'H376.IIIA.51',fillColor : Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2],low : 173.682800 ,
q1 : 204.015100 ,
median : 220.438400 ,
q3 : 238.150300 ,
high : 284.302400 ,
},{x : 2 ,
name : 'H376.IIIA.52',fillColor : Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2],low : 137.793700 ,
q1 : 143.842300 ,
median : 163.880200 ,
q3 : 187.011900 ,
high : 195.850400 ,
}]},{
name : 'Sample Level',id : 'a3' ,
type : 'boxplot', 
data: [{x : 0 ,
name : 'H376.IIIB.50',fillColor : Highcharts.getOptions().colors[3],low : 131.268200 ,
q1 : 163.241100 ,
median : 179.796100 ,
q3 : 202.282100 ,
high : 230.989900 ,
},{x : 1 ,
name : 'H376.IIIB.51',fillColor : Highcharts.getOptions().colors[3],low : 86.757760 ,
q1 : 117.577890 ,
median : 132.732950 ,
q3 : 152.025730 ,
high : 192.695230 ,
},{x : 2 ,
name : 'H376.IIIB.52',fillColor : Highcharts.getOptions().colors[3],low : 55.805900 ,
q1 : 112.396400 ,
median : 148.136700 ,
q3 : 158.304000 ,
high : 195.066600 ,
},{x : 3 ,
name : 'H376.IIIB.53',fillColor : Highcharts.getOptions().colors[3],low : 58.977680 ,
q1 : 117.296550 ,
median : 128.859540 ,
q3 : 156.513070 ,
high : 199.546430 ,
}]},{
name : 'Sample Level',id : 'a4' ,
type : 'boxplot', 
data: [{x : 0 ,
name : 'H376.IV.53',fillColor : Highcharts.getOptions().colors[4],low : 54.518200 ,
q1 : 111.829900 ,
median : 126.955700 ,
q3 : 167.103600 ,
high : 173.332000 ,
},{x : 1 ,
name : 'H376.IV.51',fillColor : Highcharts.getOptions().colors[4],low : 74.338170 ,
q1 : 74.338170 ,
median : 92.579780 ,
q3 : 110.821400 ,
high : 110.821400 ,
},{x : 2 ,
name : 'H376.IV.54',fillColor : Highcharts.getOptions().colors[4],low : 94.188410 ,
q1 : 99.934560 ,
median : 112.693950 ,
q3 : 128.572250 ,
high : 141.715820 ,
},{x : 3 ,
name : 'H376.IV.50',fillColor : Highcharts.getOptions().colors[4],low : 100.237200 ,
q1 : 112.766500 ,
median : 125.433800 ,
q3 : 143.164500 ,
high : 179.184200 ,
}]},{
name : 'Sample Level',id : 'a5' ,
type : 'boxplot', 
data: [{x : 0 ,
name : 'H376.V.51',fillColor : Highcharts.getOptions().colors[5],low : 35.449400 ,
q1 : 35.449400 ,
median : 35.449400 ,
q3 : 35.449400 ,
high : 35.449400 ,
},{x : 1 ,
name : 'H376.V.52',fillColor : Highcharts.getOptions().colors[5],low : 29.982680 ,
q1 : 34.286990 ,
median : 38.591290 ,
q3 : 88.493590 ,
high : 138.395890 ,
},{x : 2 ,
name : 'H376.V.50',fillColor : Highcharts.getOptions().colors[5],low : 70.415210 ,
q1 : 70.415210 ,
median : 77.113640 ,
q3 : 83.812070 ,
high : 83.812070 ,
},{x : 3 ,
name : 'H376.V.53',fillColor : Highcharts.getOptions().colors[5],low : 88.297040 ,
q1 : 88.847730 ,
median : 90.742780 ,
q3 : 101.693510 ,
high : 114.335300 ,
}]},{
name : 'Sample Level',id : 'a6' ,
type : 'boxplot', 
data: [{x : 0 ,
name : 'H376.VI.50',fillColor : Highcharts.getOptions().colors[6],low : 19.978470 ,
q1 : 33.245010 ,
median : 43.544760 ,
q3 : 48.099960 ,
high : 51.624160 ,
},{x : 1 ,
name : 'H376.VI.51',fillColor : Highcharts.getOptions().colors[6],low : 31.642100 ,
q1 : 32.164610 ,
median : 37.132430 ,
q3 : 48.085840 ,
high : 52.346930 ,
},{x : 2 ,
name : 'H376.VI.52',fillColor : Highcharts.getOptions().colors[6],low : 44.871530 ,
q1 : 54.775770 ,
median : 59.502240 ,
q3 : 61.644640 ,
high : 66.245100 ,
}]},{
name : 'Sample Level',id : 'a7' ,
type : 'boxplot', 
data: [{x : 0 ,
name : 'H376.VII.51',fillColor : Highcharts.getOptions().colors[7],low : 50.679100 ,
q1 : 55.191780 ,
median : 58.813590 ,
q3 : 61.126990 ,
high : 68.266470 ,
}]},{
name : 'Sample Level',id : 'a8' ,
type : 'boxplot', 
data: [{x : 0 ,
name : 'H376.VIII.51',fillColor : Highcharts.getOptions().colors[8],low : 31.582050 ,
q1 : 36.516740 ,
median : 38.112800 ,
q3 : 41.753050 ,
high : 45.391350 ,
},{x : 1 ,
name : 'H376.VIII.53',fillColor : Highcharts.getOptions().colors[8],low : 15.138200 ,
q1 : 20.485630 ,
median : 24.514430 ,
q3 : 31.944020 ,
high : 38.402530 ,
},{x : 2 ,
name : 'H376.VIII.52',fillColor : Highcharts.getOptions().colors[8],low : 31.254650 ,
q1 : 36.158770 ,
median : 43.080540 ,
q3 : 48.647270 ,
high : 49.069710 ,
},{x : 3 ,
name : 'H376.VIII.54',fillColor : Highcharts.getOptions().colors[8],low : 29.982540 ,
q1 : 37.724630 ,
median : 38.905040 ,
q3 : 43.192630 ,
high : 47.503550 ,
},{x : 4 ,
name : 'H376.VIII.50',fillColor : Highcharts.getOptions().colors[8],low : 18.364200 ,
q1 : 21.713240 ,
median : 28.317500 ,
q3 : 29.632050 ,
high : 30.181980 ,
}]},{
name : 'Sample Level',id : 'a9' ,
type : 'boxplot', 
data: [{x : 0 ,
name : 'H376.IX.51',fillColor : Highcharts.getOptions().colors[9],low : 18.499100 ,
q1 : 25.018110 ,
median : 27.265820 ,
q3 : 30.193080 ,
high : 34.018780 ,
},{x : 1 ,
name : 'H376.IX.52',fillColor : Highcharts.getOptions().colors[9],low : 20.737510 ,
q1 : 29.404290 ,
median : 38.818180 ,
q3 : 42.059360 ,
high : 47.378440 ,
},{x : 2 ,
name : 'H376.IX.50',fillColor : Highcharts.getOptions().colors[9],low : 21.901050 ,
q1 : 27.844320 ,
median : 31.723080 ,
q3 : 36.269800 ,
high : 40.125680 ,
}]},{
name : 'Sample Level',id : 'a10' ,
type : 'boxplot', 
data: [{x : 0 ,
name : 'H376.X.51',fillColor : Highcharts.getOptions().colors[10],low : 29.636940 ,
q1 : 33.700180 ,
median : 38.866100 ,
q3 : 43.252390 ,
high : 47.351450 ,
},{x : 1 ,
name : 'H376.X.50',fillColor : Highcharts.getOptions().colors[10],low : 22.025020 ,
q1 : 23.293910 ,
median : 26.732280 ,
q3 : 27.945590 ,
high : 27.945590 ,
},{x : 2 ,
name : 'H376.X.53',fillColor : Highcharts.getOptions().colors[10],low : 23.584460 ,
q1 : 26.252890 ,
median : 29.070250 ,
q3 : 34.041760 ,
high : 36.966480 ,
},{x : 3 ,
name : 'H376.X.52',fillColor : Highcharts.getOptions().colors[10],low : 28.171270 ,
q1 : 35.589200 ,
median : 46.177590 ,
q3 : 54.882440 ,
high : 62.534710 ,
}]},{
name : 'Sample Level',id : 'a11' ,
type : 'boxplot', 
data: [{x : 0 ,
name : 'H376.XI.60',fillColor : Highcharts.getOptions().colors[11],low : 31.872340 ,
q1 : 34.590770 ,
median : 35.915730 ,
q3 : 40.943930 ,
high : 45.183150 ,
},{x : 1 ,
name : 'H376.XI.50',fillColor : Highcharts.getOptions().colors[11],low : 29.211650 ,
q1 : 32.551010 ,
median : 34.862020 ,
q3 : 38.254160 ,
high : 38.599670 ,
},{x : 2 ,
name : 'H376.XI.52',fillColor : Highcharts.getOptions().colors[11],low : 37.282150 ,
q1 : 49.405780 ,
median : 53.948130 ,
q3 : 61.213390 ,
high : 73.643200 ,
},{x : 3 ,
name : 'H376.XI.53',fillColor : Highcharts.getOptions().colors[11],low : 21.557980 ,
q1 : 22.566930 ,
median : 28.112760 ,
q3 : 32.631470 ,
high : 37.610770 ,
},{x : 4 ,
name : 'H376.XI.54',fillColor : Highcharts.getOptions().colors[11],low : 10.235750 ,
q1 : 23.119470 ,
median : 27.280010 ,
q3 : 33.253340 ,
high : 47.279650 ,
},{x : 5 ,
name : 'H376.XI.56',fillColor : Highcharts.getOptions().colors[11],low : 15.264730 ,
q1 : 22.514070 ,
median : 26.566710 ,
q3 : 29.137690 ,
high : 33.186450 ,
}]},
            ]
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/drilldown.js"></script>

<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 710px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Any one knows how to add outliers to the drilldown boxplot(the one after you click any of these appears first)?

Comment: Could you attach version with outliners?

Comment: The fact is I can not add outliers to drilldown boxplot. for different series shall make a new figure. I shall edit the post to add the outliers which I would have but in fact covers the boxplot, in case that is what you want.

Comment: I added outliers for drilldown boxplot 'a0', but this presented here does not cover the boxplot as expect. Neither does it present the outliers. Wish this could be helpful for you to give me any clue. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe another, could you attach mockup how it should looks like (a image or something)

Comment: I need 10 reputation to add a picture. The very point is that the boxplot should contains outliers, but if you click the x-axis and go into the drilldown, boxplots there have nothing.

Comment: You can use any imageshack or other hosting and add url here

Comment: never thought of imagrshack! would it be possible? thanks! http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img537/7262/QwArPW.png

Comment: At this moment drilldown allows to drill into single serie. So you need to destroy chart and create new one to have more than one serie.

Comment: I see... I had got that sense, but that would make it harder for I am not familiar with making drilldown in that way. Thank you.