# Overlay individual data points for rCharts / highcharts boxplot

Tags: r, highcharts, boxplot, rcharts

I am trying to overlay individual subjects' data-points/scores to boxplots I've created with rCharts. I have seen one option from HighCharts is to create the boxplots as '[objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28959612/how-to-make-highcharts-boxplot-with-drilldown)' which may be a clue as to how to get an individual's points into the boxplots (and this leaves open the ability to loop over all the individuals' scores across all categories).

My Vanilla boxplots are:

```
#Box-Plots
#Create a new Highchart
h2 <- Highcharts$new()
h2$set(series = list(list(name = "all scores", data = cat.stats)))

#Add axis details
h2$xAxis(
  categories = levels(longdata$category)
)

h2$yAxis(
  min = 0,
  max = 100,
  tickInterval = 10,
  title = list(text = 'Scores (%)')  
)

#Define the type of plot
h2$chart(
  type = 'boxplot',
  inverted = 'true')

#Give it a title
h2$title(
  text = 'Your functioning across four domains and overall compared to the whole group'
)
h2
```

Which gives me:
[image]

What I want though is handled in STATA (but without the interactivity):
[image]

What would be great is also the ability to add in a 'cut-score' line in the 'overall' category.

Comment: If you want to add a red point as in you second image you could add an error bar series. Is that what you need?

Comment: That's a good idea, and that is exactly how I code up the STATA 'cut-off point'. So should have thought of it already. But I still need 'an' individual's score (the black dots as shown in the STATA image) within the boxplots to make things right.

Comment: For the black dots you could use a scatter type series. I could post an answer with code using exemplary data if you will have further problems with this.